# Toggling popup DIV tags not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to make a simple page with a few divs, where if you click on one div it moves to the center and getting bigger (other divs still visible in the background). When you click on another div visible in the background the div in the center goes back to where it was before and clicked div goes to the center and resizing. Also if you click on the div in the center it should go back to where it was before. 
I made a Jquery script for it but it doesnt work properly - clicking   on any div first time works fine but any following clicking just stops working. 
Here is an html with some styling:

```
<style>
#outside1 {background-color:gray;}   #outside2 {background-color:blue;}        #outside3 {background-color:brown;}
#inside1 {background-color:red;}     #inside2 {background-color:green;}   
#inside3 {background-color:pink;}    #inside4 {background-color:yellow;}
#inside5 {background-color:gold;}    #inside6 {background-color:silver;}

.outside {width:100px; height:90px; margin:5px; }   .inside {display:none; margin:2px;  }
#test1 {height:400px; }
</style>


<div id=test1>
<div id='outside1' class='outside'> div outside 1 <br/>
<div id='inside1' class='inside'> div inside 1 <br/>   </div>
<div id='inside2' class='inside'> div inside 2 <br/>   </div>
</div> 

<div id='outside2' class='outside'> div outside 2 <br/>
<div id='inside3' class='inside'> div inside 3 <br/>   </div>
<div id='inside4' class='inside'> div inside 4 <br/>   </div>
</div> 

<div id='outside3' class='outside'> div outside 2 <br/>
<div id='inside5' class='inside'> div inside 3 <br/>   </div>
<div id='inside6' class='inside'> div inside 4 <br/>   </div>
</div> 

</div>
```

And thats some js and jquery:

```
kd_small={top: 0, left: 0,  opacity: 1, width:100, height:90 } ;
kd_big = {top: -90, left: +50,  opacity: 1, width:200, height:150 };
var t=0; 

function hextend(d){
  d.animate(kd_big);       d.find('div').show();        $('.outside').off();   
  var sbs=$(d).siblings();  $(sbs).off(); sbs.append('i am siblings');      
  d.append('I AM CLICKED');   hshrink($(sbs));   
  d.on('click', function (){ hshrink($(d));   });
  $(sbs).on('click', function (){ hextend($(sbs));   });
}

function hshrink(s){
 s.find('div').hide(); s.animate(kd_small);    
}

$('.outside').on('click', function(){
  hextend($(this) ); 
});

$('.inside').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();  $(this).html('inside div clicked' + t +'times');  
  t++;  
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.on('click'` use `delegate('click'` or `.live('click', as you are appending divs.

However, both .live and .delegate have been superseded, so I imagine this would be a 'quick fix'.

Looking again at the code, I think you may have to use 'addClass' to add the correct class to the div's you are appending, and use the console to check the elements once they are centered and make sure the classes exist for the elements.